# How do I make an swf close automatically after finishing playing on a website?

Tags: flash

How do I make an swf close automatically after finishing playing?
I would like to use the action script within `flash` to do so.

I've put a `stop();` so it doesn't loop, but now I need an action to completely close
as the `swf` is going on top of the website.

Here's an example - http://www.godrichinteriors.com/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a javascript method like below in your HTML,

`function closeSWF(){
// code to close the swf
}`

Then you need to call this function from swf like

`ExternalInterface.call("closeSWF");`

You need to include `import flash.external.ExternalInterface;`

in your flash code.

Hope this helps.